# Failed to start Kubernetes API Server duo to unknown reason

Tags: kubernetes, etcd, kubelet

the service is not starting and the listener is not activated on port 8080.

here is my kubernetes configuration:

```
KUBE_LOGTOSTDERR="--logtostderr=true"
KUBE_LOG_LEVEL="--v=0"
KUBE_ALLOW_PRIV="--allow-privileged=false"
KUBE_MASTER="--master=http://centos-master:8080"
KUBE_ETCD_SERVERS="--etcd-servers=http://centos-master:2379"
```

systemctl status kube-apiserver -l

```
● kube-apiserver.service - Kubernetes API Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/kube-apiserver.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Mon 2017-08-14 12:07:04 +0430; 29s ago
     Docs: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes
  Process: 2087 ExecStart=/usr/bin/kube-apiserver $KUBE_LOGTOSTDERR $KUBE_LOG_LEVEL $KUBE_ETCD_SERVERS $KUBE_API_ADDRESS $KUBE_API_PORT $KUBELET_PORT $KUBE_ALLOW_PRIV $KUBE_SERVICE_ADDRESSES $KUBE_ADMISSION_CONTROL $KUBE_API_ARGS (code=exited, status=2)
 Main PID: 2087 (code=exited, status=2)

Aug 14 12:07:04 centos-master systemd[1]: kube-apiserver.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
Aug 14 12:07:04 centos-master systemd[1]: Failed to start Kubernetes API Server.
Aug 14 12:07:04 centos-master systemd[1]: Unit kube-apiserver.service entered failed state.
Aug 14 12:07:04 centos-master systemd[1]: kube-apiserver.service failed.
Aug 14 12:07:04 centos-master systemd[1]: kube-apiserver.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Aug 14 12:07:04 centos-master systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for kube-apiserver.service
Aug 14 12:07:04 centos-master systemd[1]: Failed to start Kubernetes API Server.
Aug 14 12:07:04 centos-master systemd[1]: Unit kube-apiserver.service entered failed state.
Aug 14 12:07:04 centos-master systemd[1]: kube-apiserver.service failed.
```

tail -n 1000 /var/log/messages

```
resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.0.2.4:8080: getsockopt: connection refused
Aug 14 12:12:30 centos-master kube-scheduler: E0814 12:12:30.240160     606 reflector.go:199] k8s.io/kubernetes/plugin/pkg/scheduler/factory/factory.go:466: Failed to list *api.PersistentVolume: Get http://centos-master:8080/api/v1/persistentvolumes?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.0.2.4:8080: getsockopt: connection refused
Aug 14 12:12:30 centos-master kube-scheduler: E0814 12:12:30.242039     606 reflector.go:199] k8s.io/kubernetes/plugin/pkg/scheduler/factory/factory.go:470: Failed to list *api.Service: Get http://centos-master:8080/api/v1/services?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.0.2.4:8080: getsockopt: connection refused
Aug 14 12:12:30 centos-master kube-scheduler: E0814 12:12:30.242924     606 reflector.go:199] k8s.io/kubernetes/plugin/pkg/scheduler/factory/factory.go:457: Failed to list *api.Pod: Get http://centos-master:8080/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=spec.nodeName%3D%2Cstatus.phase%21%3DFailed%2Cstatus.phase%21%3DSucceeded&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.0.2.4:8080: getsockopt: connection refused
Aug 14 12:12:30 centos-master kube-scheduler: E0814 12:12:30.269386     606 reflector.go:199] k8s.io/kubernetes/plugin/pkg/scheduler/factory/factory.go:473: Failed to list *api.ReplicationController: Get http://centos-master:8080/api/v1/replicationcontrollers?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.0.2.4:8080: getsockopt: connection refused
Aug 14 12:12:30 centos-master kube-scheduler: E0814 12:12:30.285782     606 reflector.go:199] k8s.io/kubernetes/plugin/pkg/scheduler/factory/factory.go:481: Failed to list *extensions.ReplicaSet: Get http://centos-master:8080/apis/extensions/v1beta1/replicasets?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.0.2.4:8080: getsockopt: connection refused
Aug 14 12:12:30 centos-master kube-scheduler: E0814 12:12:30.286529     606 reflector.go:199] pkg/controller/informers/factory.go:89: Failed to list *api.PersistentVolumeClaim: Get http://centos-master:8080/api/v1/persistentvolumeclaims?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.0.2.4:8080: getsockopt: connection refused
```

Comment: firewalld is disabled ,and ETCD_LISTEN_CLIENT_URLS="http://0.0.0.0:2379",ETCD_ADVERTISE_CLIENT_URLS="http://0.0.0.0:2379", my environment is 4 virtual machines running in local nat in addition to their basic network by box

Comment: what version your using?  you can use `kubeadm` command to configure your cluster.

Comment: `kubeadm` is new tools, it takes care of configuring the master and node. its easy to use.

Comment: thanks a lot i'm trying

Answer (score 0):

```
systemd[1]: kube-apiserver.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
```

The arguments you're using do not seem valid.

Check the list of valid arguments [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/kube-apiserver/).

You can also follow the [Kubernetes The Hard Way](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way/blob/master/docs/05-kubernetes-controller.md) guide for a trusted way to run the API server.